# A question on non commutative ring or algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, c-star-algebras

Assume that $R$ is  a ring such that $R=I+J$ where $I$ and $J$ are 2 -sided ideal.(This  is  not a direct sum) If $I$ and $J$ are  commutative does it implies that $R$ is  a  commutative ring?  Please consider the same  question for $C^{*}$  algebra $A$. (In this question $R$ or $A$ can be unital or non unital) If the answer is  no, what is the counter example in the area of $C^{*}$  algebras?

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you very much for your comment. I googled Ito theorem but there is no a wikipedia link. What is the Ito theorem? Any way do you mean the answer to my question is "Yes" or "No", since  a  C* algebra is automatically a lie algebra?

Comment: See [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4675) for a modern reference of Ito's theorem for Lie algebras. $L=A+B$ is metabelian, but need not be abelian in general, if the subalgebras $A$ and $B$ are abelian. But you require that both are even ideals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closed commutative ideal in a C$^*$-algebra is necessarily contained in the centre of the algebra (proof below). So if $A=I+J$ with $I,J$ commutative ideals, then $A$ is commutative as $A\subset Z(A)\subset A$, so $A=Z(A)$.

To show that a commutative ideal is central: let $x\in A$ and $y\in J^+$, where $J$ is a commutative ideal. Then $y=z^*z$, with $z\in J$ (as $J$ is a C$^*$-algebra). Then
$$
xy=xz^*z=(xz^*)z=z(xz^*)=(zx)z^*=z^*zx=yx.
$$
As the positive elements in $J$ span $J$, we get $xy=yx$ for all $x\in A$, $y\in J$.

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting answer.What about banch algebras/Is there a counter example?